# How to make a slide on panel with html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a panel that should slide from the left. The panel should have the links on it. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boratsagddiev/n8L4f0am/6/)

```
    <div id='section'>My main context goes here</div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

The problem is that this panel does not cover the objects from the main container. How can I make this panel to cover all object and look nice ?

Comment: Which objects from the main container aren't covered?

Comment: All of them. I think I need to use `z-index:9999` but i am not sure

Answer (score 2):

It is a z-index issue.

Whatever you want to be on top just needs to be higher than everything else.

By default, elements are at '0' and you can go from there.